# What is the meaning of the following android error: "Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::AutofillDriver"

Tags: android, android-studio

As a beginner in developing android apps I have created a rather large app, and now I get the following error (without any backtrace) while the app is running on a physical device:

```
[ERROR:interface_registry.cc(99)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::AutofillDriver
```

Since a google search with exact these terms returned 0 hints, I am asking the question here.

Additional information:

- Android Studio 2.1.3
- Physical device: LG G1

Comment: Are you using a webview in your app?

Comment: Not that I am aware of

Comment: can you post some code where you encountered this error

Comment: I have no idea where this happens. But some android experts must have seen this error before, no?

Comment: I had encountered this error when i was trying to load a webpage in my android app

Comment: It this then some 'connection' error, or can this problem affect the working of the entire app?

Comment: @Alex are you showing any ads in your app? ad networks usually use webview when displaying ads so it might be related